# Error 127 with cake command

Tags: php, shell, cakephp, server, system-administration

I create a Shell Task with CakePHP 2.x and i want to execute it through a Controller. So, i create a function that execute a command on cli to run the Shell Task. Here are my files :

```
// I want to launch it in background task
$pid = exec(APP . 'Console/cake {myCommand} {myTask} {argument} >/dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!', $output, $return_var);

debug($pid);
debug($output);
debug($return_var);
```

It renders :

```
// line xx
''
// line xx
array()
// line xx
(int) 127
```

I tried to launch only the `cake` command like this :

```
$pid = exec(APP . 'Console/cake', $output, $return_var);
```

And i get the same result. It seems the shell doesn't find the full path, but it's weird because it's the right path. I tested it in my machine in developpement, it works perfectly.

Do you have any idea were it can come from ?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you calling a Cake shell task from a controller? This sounds completely wrong. If there is shared code used from both the browser and command line then this functionality is better placed in a model that can be called by both the task and controller.

Comment: Because we want to launch this shell script from an URL in the browser. It's a long-running background task and we don't want to "block" the user during this process.

Comment: Can this not be automated via a cronjob instead? `exec()` should really be avoided. If you need to be able to trigger it from the browser perhaps you should consider using something like the Queue plugin (https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-queue) to trigger the task.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It seems to be a good idea. I'll look into this plugin.

Answer (score 0):

172 is the actually meaning of what you figured out, see http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html

> but it's weird because it's the right path

Honestly, I doubt the system is lying. So check the path on your target machine and not only in your dev environment.

Also check if the user who is executing the script is allowed to do so. Linux permissions can be fun. You could try to set 777 for the `cake` file, and make sure it is executable as well.

Comment: Sorry, my answer is a little late but I was testing your suggestions. Finally, I don't execute my task with the Controller but with a cron job set on my server. I work with a CakePHP-Queue plugin to add new tasks from my Controller.
But, for the error 127, I found errors of execution by replacing `exec` with `proc_open`. The file `Console/cake` execute commands like `dirname`, `basename`,... but not with the full path (eg : `/usr/bin/dirname`) and, I think it's the problem.